# Power BI Errors Showing Up For Values That No Longer Exist

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, m

I made some changes to my dataset in Power BI via the Power Query Editor.

I went to close the editor and apply my changes to the data.

I get "Query Errors" that appear, despite having handled the records. I've confirmed the error does not appear in any other columns.

When I go to apply the changes, the errors still appear.

Any suggestions?

Edit #1:

I tried changing the column to a text data type and then sorting to look at all of the values, but it says "Invalid cell value: '#N/A', which is weird. I wonder why it won't let me sort the data.

Comment: What does `I get "Query Editors" that appear` mean?

Comment: That was a typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only way you can handle these types of values are to handle them outside of Power BI. Power BI cannot handle these values at this time.